# Коцюрбитися, коцюрба - чи однокорінні ці слова?

Tags: значення-слів

СУМ [дає](http://sum.in.ua/s/kocjurbytysja) таке тлумачення слова *коцюрбитися*

> **КОЦЮРБИТИСЯ**:  Гнутися, кривитися, скручуватися.

Слово *коцюрба* в СУМ відсутнє, про те є у [Грінченка](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/24402-kocjurba.html)

> **Коцюрба**, -би, ж. Черемуха, Prunus padus.

Інформаційно-розважальний сайт ВСВІТІ [наводить](http://vsviti.com.ua/ukraine/77914) інше значення слова *коцюрба*

> **Коцюрба** – страва, ... маленькі галушки з тіста, картопля, шкварки і часник перемішуються у макітрі і все це разом подається у тій же посудині.

Здавалося б що слово *коцюрбитися* мало б бути похідним від *коцюрба* однак за змістом вони досить далекі. Чи можливо є інші тлумачення цих слів, ближчі один до одного за змістом? Якщо все ж таки ці слова не поєднані - чи є в такому випадку вони однокореневими?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Коцюба́** або кочерга́ — знаряддя у вигляді насадженого на держак залізного прута з розплесканим загнутим кінцем для перемішування палива, прочищення колосників в печі й вигрібання з неї жару, попелу.

У сучасній українській мові слова «**коцюба**» і «кочерга» вважають синонімами[[8]](http://sum.in.ua/s/kocjuba). Проте, у деяких місцевостях України вони мають різні значення. Слово «**коцюба**» має дві версії походження.

Згідно з першою, *воно є запозиченням з тюркських мов*, пор. чаг. косагу, казах. косау («палиця, якою мішають вогонь»), тур. kusku («лом»), кирг. козо. Джерело цієї версії - Етимологічний словник української мови у 7 томах. К.: Наукова думка, 1982 - 2009.

За другою, *воно питомо слов'янське і споріднене* зі словами коцюбити, **коцюрбити**, коцюбнути, коцюрга (палиця)[[12]](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/24403-kocjurgha.html#show_point), **коцюрба** (черемха)[[13]](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/24402-kocjurba.html#show_point): тоді її тлумачать як «гнута», «викривлена».

(с) [Wiki](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%86%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B0_(%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B4%D1%8F))